# Why myClassObj++++ doesn't incur a compile error : '++' needs l-value just as buildin type do?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, lvalue

Why myint++++ compiles fine with VS2008 compiler and gcc 3.42 compiler ?? I was expecting compiler say need lvalue, example see below.

```
struct MyInt
{
    MyInt(int i):m_i(i){}

    MyInt& operator++() //return reference,  return a lvalue
    {
        m_i += 1;
        return *this;
    }

    //operator++ need it's operand to be a modifiable lvalue
    MyInt operator++(int)//return a copy,  return a rvalue
    {
        MyInt tem(*this);
        ++(*this);
        return tem;
    }

    int     m_i;
};

int main()
{
    //control: the buildin type int
    int i(0);
    ++++i;  //compile ok
    //i++++; //compile error :'++' needs l-value, this is expected

    //compare 
    MyInt  myint(1);
    ++++myint;//compile ok
    myint++++;//expecting compiler say need lvalue , but compiled fine !? why ??
}
```

Comment: The compiler also fails to notice that `++++i;` is wrong.

Comment: @MSalters: Is `++++i` actually wrong?

Comment: Yes. Modifying `i` twice without an intervening sequence point, that's wrong.

Comment: @MSalters: Ah, yes, sequence points.  I was thinking only of lvalues and rvalues.

Comment: @Oli, @MSalters: ++++i is well-formed, but it has UB. I don't think the compiler is wrong to accept it :)

Comment: return a const MyInt instead, it achieves what you want and is better practice as it makes it hard for users to do something 'wrong' with your class. See Effective C++ chapter on returning const objects from operator + as well.

Comment: @MSalters: How is this modifying twice without intervening sequence points? That's only a concern in an expressions like `++i - ++i`, where `operator-` has two arguments and it's undefined which (or, indeed, _if any_) one of these is evaluated first. But in `++++i`, there is just one argument `++i` for the outer `operator++`, which _must_ be fully evaluated first for the outer `operator++` to start. It is no more undefined than `std::cout<<"1st"<<"2nd"`. (This just does not necessarily apply for internal types, where `operator++` is not guaranteed to be an actual function.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout: You're talking about order of evaluation. That's another matter (and OoE is _unspecified_, not _undefined_). The problem is that `++(++i)` does indeed evaluate the inner `(++i)` first, but then - without sequence point - goes on to modify the same `i` again. So we know the specific order of evaluation, and we know that it is necessary wrong.

Comment: Another silly question that would never happen in real code. Not only is it unreadable. It is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Martin: Calling ++++ on an object of class type is not only well-formed, but has well-defined behavior. Since ++ in that case is a function call, it introduces a sequence point

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: Are you seriously going to argue that point (being obtuse just to make a point is tiresome). Do you think you will ever see code like that in the wild! Do you think any other engineer would let you get away with checking that into source control. The fact that it is well defined for classes is neither here nor there. The problem is that it is not well defined for POD. This fact makes it a maintenance nightmare. Since the function you wrote one year ago is now naively transformed into a template and somebody start using it with integers (**BANG** there goes your well defined).

Comment: @Martin: I am not arguing that it's OK to write something like that in production code. But I do insist it's well defined for objects of class type, including for POD-structs. Where did you get the idea that it's not well-defined for POD-structs?

Comment: @MSalters: there _is_ a sequence point here, after evaluation of the inner `operator++` is finished and before the outer `operator++` is entered. That is the point I was trying to make.

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: Repeating the same thing once I explained why it is irrelevant does not make it any corrector. It is not well defined for all POD.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Sorry, no. `operator++` for built-in types is not a function call, and therefore there's no sequence point before or after it. @Martin: Armen's right: if it's a POD class, `++` is a function call with sequence points before and after.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, overloaded operators are not operators - they're functions. So GCC is correct to accept
that.

`myobj++++;` is equivalent to `myobj.operator++(0).operator++(0);`
Caling a member function (including overloaded operator) on a temprorary object of class type is allowed.

Comment: This is not correct: overloaded operators are both operators **and** functions. The important bit is that the *requirements* for user defined operators are those of the implementation of the operator, which might differ depending on *how* you implement it. In this particular case as a member function.

Answer (score 3):

Because for user-defined types, operator overloads are literally just function calls, and so obey the semantics of function calls.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to emulate the built-in behaviour there’s actually a very simple solution: make the return value `const`:

```
MyInt const operator++(int) { … }
```

A few years back there was a debate over whether user-defined operators should *exactly* model the built-in behaviour. I’m not sure which school of thought currently has the upper hand, but making the return type of `operator++(int)` `const` was a way of achieving this.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, `MyInt::operator++(int)` is just another method. The same rules apply. Since you can call methods on rvalues, you can call `operator++(int)` on rvalues.

Answer (score 1):

myint++ returns something similar to MyInt(2). So, it's similar to doing MyInt(2)++. A temporary class is created in the operator++ function and you're incrementing the temporary class. After it's returned, it's deleted as soon as the next statement finishes (here, it's second ++ operator).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the requirements of the postincrement operator for integral types and for user defined types are different. In particular a user defined postincrement operator implemented as a member function allow the use of rvalues.

If you had implemented the operator as a free function:

```
MyInt operator++(MyInt [const][&] x, int)
```

Then the requirements of that particular operator would be those extracted from the actual signature. If the first argument is taken by value, then it accepts rvalues directly, if it takes the argument by `const &` then it accepts rvalues if the copy constructor is accessible, if the argument is taken by non constant `&` then that operator will require lvalues.