# Iterator to last element of std::vector using end()--

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

I have a `std::vector` and I want the `iterator` to the last element in the vector; I will be storing this iterator for later use.

NOTE: I want an iterator reference to it, not `std::vector::back`. Because I want to be able to compute the index of this object from the `std::vector::begin` later on.

The following is my logic to get the iterator to the last element:

```
std::vector<int> container;
std::vector<int>::iterator it = container.end()--;
```

Since `std::vector::end` has O(1) time complexity, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. So what's the question?

Comment: You need `--container.end()` instead of `container.end()--`. Also you need to make sure the container isn't empty first, or you'll have undefined behavior.

Comment: aha, I see by doing `std::vector<int>::iterator it = container.end()--` I will get the `end` iterator then decrements the iterator

Comment: What else are you going to do with the iterator, Apart from computing the index to the last element? If nothing else, you may just store the index. Either way, the iterator or index might be invalid by the time you actually use them.

Comment: @LukeLee I will be storing the object and the iterator to the object in a map. I want to be able to look up the object in O(1) and get the index. the index would change as the content of the vector can be removed and added

Comment: If you are messing with the vector's contents in a way that invalidates the index, then that will certainly invalidate the iterator too.

Comment: @T.C. I will be syncing the vector and the map; so anything that is removed from the vector will be removed from map.
also 
i.e `vector = [ 5,1,4,2,3]`
if I get an iterator to the end which is `3`, then remove `1`. I can still use the iterator from `3` to get to `5`(the front) with out a problem.

Comment: @quark How would the iterator magically know there's one less item to subtract?

Comment: Any operation that invalidates an index invalidates the iterator corresponding to said index. (`erase`, for instance, invalidates every iterator at or after the point of the erase.) Using such an iterator results in undefined behavior.

Comment: I rolled back the last edit because changing the question invalidated some of the answers.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I think you mean either:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator it = --container.end();
std::vector<int>::iterator it = container.end() - 1;
std::vector<int>::iterator it = std::prev(container.end());
```

You're unintentionally just returning `end()`. But the problem with all of these is what happens when the vector is empty, otherwise they're all do the right thing in constant time. Though if the vector is empty, there's no last element anyway.

Also be careful when storing iterators - they can get invalidated.

Note that if `vector<T>::iterator` is just `T*` (which would be valid), the first form above is ill-formed. The second two work regardless, so are preferable.

Comment: The first one is invalid if the iterator is a pointer. The other two are fine.

Comment: And the second one is restricted to random access containers.

Comment: @MSalters The question is about `std::vector`

Comment: @T.C. why would the first be invalid? Decrementing pointers is a common operation.

Comment: @MarkRansom could you expand of the rvalue issue? I used --container.end() to get the last element and it works.

Comment: @quark rvalues are temporary values, and it makes no sense to modify them; that's why the modifying operators `++` and `--` are disallowed. See [What exactly is a R-Value in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406121/what-exactly-is-a-r-value-in-c). But if the temporary is a class type, the operator isn't applied directly but is converted to a `operator--` call, which is allowed on an rvalue - see [Why myClassObj++++ doesn't incur a compile error : '++' needs l-value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692037/why-myclassobj-doesnt-incur-a-compile-error-needs-l-value-just-as-bu).

Answer (score 17):

You have `rbegin` that does what you need

[cplusplus reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/rbegin/)

```
auto last = container.rbegin();
```

Comment: But `rbegin` doesn't return an iterator, it returns a reverse_iterator.

Comment: @MarkRansom Which is a type of iterator, just not a `std::vector<int>::iterator`.

Comment: another solution would just be to save an integer index `.size()`, instead of an iterator.

Comment: @dau_sama Shouldn't it be `size-1`? Otherwise the index will point past the last element.

Comment: it is reverse_iterator, will lead to error. so container.end() - 1 is better.

Answer (score 14):

The way you are doing it will give you the wrong iterator because *post increment* will not change the value until *after* the assignment.

There is always this:

```
auto it = std::prev(container.end());
```

Remember to check first that the container is not empty so your iterator exists in a valid range.