# Subtracting 1 vs decrementing an iterator

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator, undefined-behavior, pointer-arithmetic

In [the accepted answer to "Iterator to last element of std::vector using end()--"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37017416/3777717) @barry states:

> Note that if vector::iterator is just T* (which would be valid), the first form above is ill-formed. The second two work regardless, so are preferable.

referring to his code:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator it = --container.end();
std::vector<int>::iterator it = container.end() - 1;
std::vector<int>::iterator it = std::prev(container.end());
```

This opinion is disputed in the comments, however without a clear resolution. So that's my question: what exactly is the semantic difference between the first and the second? And would the answer be different for iterators over structures other than `vector`?

Comment: The last comment by Mark Ransom _"rvalues are temporary values..."_ seems to answer the question here.  Do you have a question or some confusion about that comment?

Comment: So the answer is that indeed, the first line can cause undefined behaviour? And that happens when the iterator type (of any container) is a type which doesn't overload the `--` operator? If so, I'd accept an answer to this effect.

Comment: As far as I understand, for a `std::vector` all 3 possibilities are fines.  I don't see the problem with `--container.end()`. `end()` returns an iterator and `--` decrement it. As a general rule, any syntax that is valid with raw pointer should also be valid with `std::vector`.

Comment: @Phil1970 `std::vector` can use raw pointers for its iterator type, in which case `--` won't work.

Comment: @ByteEater If an iterator is not reversible, then trying to use `--` won't compile.

Comment: @ByteEater The first line will either work as expected, or fail to compile, depending on the implementation. It won't be Undefined Behavior for well implemented containers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For any standard library container, the member function `end()` returns an r-value.  It's a "temporary" until you assign it to a variable.

The decrement operator `--` is not required to work on r-value iterators.  You would be modifying a temporary, which C++ historically has taken measures to avoid.

Therefore, `--container.end()` **might compile** on your standard-conforming C++compiler.  But it might not.

`std::prev(container.end())` will work on **every** standard-conforming compiler.

---

**To review:**

- `--container.end()` may not compile.  It is up to the implementation.
- `container.end() - 1` will only compile if the container uses random-access iterators.
- `std::prev(container.end())` will always compile.

All three forms will produce the same result, if they compile.

Comment: It gives much relevant information, thanks. You're clearly knowledgeable in this, so could you, please, make your answer fully adequate to my question and add these missing pieces:

Comment: What kind of error is `--container.end()`? A compile-time error (if so, is it about wrong types, and why just might – doesn't the standard dictate these unambiguously?)? Undefined behaviour? Something else?

Comment: Is `container.end() - 1` always equivalent to `std::prev(container.end())`? If not (I imagine you could define an iterator type for your own container type which overloads `-` or `--` and have whatever semantics you implement), is it guaranteed for standard library containers?

Comment: (This comment added after your first edit.) You wrote: "Therefore, `--container.end()` might compile on your standard-conforming C++compiler. But it might not." So, if I understand correctly, the standard says `end` should return an iterator but leaves the exact type as implementation-defined? If so, does it require that if `--container.end()` compiles, its semantics is the same?

Comment: (This comment added after your second edit.) Does it also require that if a random-access iterator is used (as I suppose, mandatory for `vector`, but optional (implementation-defined) for some other containers), `container.end() - 1` has the same semantics?

Comment: Drew, Is `container.end() - 1` valid if the vector is empty?

Comment: Does there is a compiler on which the first line does not compile? Maybe if one would try to compile pre C++ 11 STL with post C++ 11 compiler? I was not aware that -- operator was not working on r-value. Probably because, I never write such expression in practice.